# PyMongo Cursor Iteration

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking to create and handle a cursor in python the way cursors natively work in mongo. I know the intended way is to do 'result = collection.find()' and do a 'for record in result' but I'm looking to wrap iteration functionality in a class. I'd like to be able to create a new class object and call a function e.g. init_cursor() to make a db connection and do a find returning a cursor. I would then like the have a get_next() function that would move to the next result and set class data members based on the result. Here's the pesudo-code:

```
class dataIter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = pymongo.Connection().db.collection
        self.cursor = self.collection.find({}) #return all
        self.age = None
        self.gender = None

    def get_next(self):
        if self.cursor.hasNext():
            data = self.cursor.next()
            self.set_data(data)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.age = data['age']
        self.gender = data['gender']
```

This way I would be able to simply call:

```
obj.get_next()
age = obj.age
gender = obj.gender
```

or some other help functions to pull data out of each document

Comment: If you are going to wrap a cursor, you should build in some mechanism to refresh the connection each time. A cursor should not be held onto persistently like you are doing in your init. It would have to be discarded and refreshed. The idea is to get your cursor and extract your results into detached objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't understand how what you are showing is any more convenient that just doing:

```
col = pymongo.Connection().db.collection
cur = col.find({})

obj = next(cur, None)
if obj:
    age = obj['age']
    gender = obj['gender']
```

Its not clear how this wrapper is helpful. Also, if what you are really after is an ORM, then don't reinvent the wheel when this exists: http://mongoengine.org/

Comment: Thanks for mongoengine, wasn't aware that existed. The wrapper essentially allows me to load documents and derive functionality based on the objects that were loaded so that the object exposed to someone using the class is abstracted.

As an example: I have an array of key objects that the class walks through to determine the most viable one. The public function call is just get_key().

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
class Cursor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # mongo connection
        self.collection = pymongo.Connection().cursorcollection
        self.loaded = False
        self.cursor = None

    # Cursor calls (for iterating through results)
    def init_cursor(self):
        """ Opens a new cursor """
        if not self.cursor:
            self.cursor = self.collection.find({})

    def get_next(self):
        """ load next object """
        if self.cursor and self.cursor.alive:
            self.set_data(next(self.cursor))
            return True
        else:
            self.cursor = None
            return False

    def has_next(self):
        """ cursor alive? """
        if self.cursor and self.cursor.alive:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Isnt it a bad idea to hold open a cursor? I thought they were supposed to be created on demand, used, and discarded once you extract your results?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the python iterator protocol, you class can look like this

```
class DataIter:
    def __init__(self):
         self.collection = pymongo.Connection().db.collection
         self.cursor = self.collection.find({}) #return all
         self.age = None
         self.gender = None
    def __iter__(self):
         return self
    def next(self):
        if self.cursor.hasNext():
            data = self.cursor.next()
            self.set_data(data)
            return self
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Then you can iterate like this

```
for c in DataIter():
    age = c.age
    gender = c.gender
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like what you have posted already to accomplish this. PyMongo cursors don't have a `haveNext` method, but they have a `next` method which will either return the next document, or raise `StopIteration` (this is specified by the Python iterator protocol).

You can also take this a step further: rather than assigning the values from the document to attributes on the class, you can use `__getattr__` which implements attribute lookup for Python classes.

Putting it all together, you might end up with something like:

```
class DataIter(object):

    def __init__(self, cursor):
        self._cursor = cursor
        self._doc = None

    def next(self):
        try:
            self._doc = self._cursor.next()
        except StopIteration:
            self._doc = None
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._doc[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('document has no attribute %r' % name)
```