# How to make a query on pymongo cursor object [mongo db]

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I have a requirement to find list of member records in a organization, In my organization there are 100 records(documents) in my collection.I have retrieved those hundred records with the following query

```
result = db.mycollection.find({'organization':'organizationName'})
```

now i want to retrieve only a list of members in the organization,now i have a list of member names like this

```
list1 = ['username1','username2','username3',....'username10']
```

now i want to get the details of the members who are in the list with the `result(pymonto cursor object)` variable.I don't want to make another query on database.Is it possible to get in that way.Thanks in advance

i am using

```
python 2.7.5
mongodb 2.4.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is acceptable:
Combine both the queries

```
db.mycollection.find({'organization':'organizationName','name':{'$in':list1}})
```

This is much more effecient than
Manually searching for objects using application logic:

```
result2=[];
for ob in result:
  if ob.get('name') in list1:
    result2.append(ob)
```

I hope this works, I am  not sure about the `pymongo` syntax. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424078/pymongo-cursor-iteration).

Comment: this is ok but is it possible to query on pymongo cursor object?